# Plot two pandas seriers to one figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, line-plot

I'm trying to plot: **line plot** and **bar plot** on the same figure but the line does not show up. Here is the code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('cars.csv')
df['Price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Price'])
m = df.groupby(['Brand', 'Year'])['Price'].mean()
s = df.groupby('Year').Price.mean()
ax = m.unstack('Brand').plot.bar()
s.plot(x=ax.get_xticks('Year'), ax=ax, kind='line', label='Mean price')
y_formatter = ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False)
plt.show()
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because bar plots treat the `x` variable as categorical, so the bars are automatically shifted down to `x=0,1,2,...` and their ticks are relabeled via `xticklabels`. You can see this by checking `ax.get_xlim()` and `ax.get_xticklabels()`.

One workaround is to plot `s` against `range(len(s))` to manually shift it down to `x=0,1,2,...`:

```py
ax = m.unstack('Brand').plot.bar(legend=False)
ax.plot(range(len(s)), s, label='Mean price')
ax.legend()
```

Alternatively `reset_index()` twice on `s` and plot with `x='index'`:

```py
ax = m.unstack('Brand').plot.bar()
s.reset_index().reset_index().plot(x='index', y='Price', ax=ax, label='Mean price')
```